# Merge multiple arrays into a multidimensional one in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

Example

```
let a = [a, b, c]
let b = [x, y, z]
```

I need this response

```
let c = [[a, b, c],[x, y, z]]
```

There are two approaches as I see it, either I concatenate both arrays (don't know if it's possible), or to append it directly in a multidimensional array.

Comment: `let c = [a, b]`

Comment: I don't think this would be an issue as long as you're dealing with the same type every time. Just set your variable type as an array. e.g. `let a: [Int] = [1,2,3], let c: [[Int]] = [a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will try to concatenate it:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = [4, 5]
let c = a + b // will receive [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let d = [a, b] // will receive multidimensional array [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
var e: [[Int]] = []
e.append(a)
e.append(b)
print(e) // should be equal to d
```